# how can I achieve buttons like these in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

how can I achieve buttons like these in flutter?
I want these buttons to be sticked to the side and floated in the screen, just like bottom-navigation but to the side not to the buttom.
I hope you all get the idea.[image: screen]

Comment: You can use Stack with RotatedBox or floatingActionButton with custom floating position

Comment: what about changing the layout between signup and sign in without changing the whole screen... I want the buttons to stiĺl in the main layout

Comment: conditional if will enough I belive and you can find many animated widgets,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**you could use RotatedBox widget something like the following:**

```
class NewButton extends StatelessWidget {
  const NewButton({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("App Today")),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {},
            child: Container(
              width: 40,
              height: 100,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Color.fromARGB(255, 54, 105, 247),
                  borderRadius:
                      BorderRadius.horizontal(right: Radius.circular(20)),
                  border: Border.all(
                      width: 2.0, color: Color.fromARGB(221, 8, 1, 24))),
              child: const RotatedBox(
                  quarterTurns: 1,
                  child: Text('REGISTER',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 18,
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center)),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: example picture]

Comment: what about changing the layout between signup and sign in without changing the whole screen... I want the buttons to stiĺl in the main layout

Comment: divide  the screen and for the right section. You can use if else statement to change its contents..

Answer (score 0):

stick to those steps:

1. create a simple `ElevatedButton`
2. customize it so it looks like what you want
3. wrap your `Scaffold` with a `Stack` widget
4. set alignment of `Stack` to `alignment: Alignment.center`
5. in the children of that `Stack`, the Scaffold should be a direct child in the `children` property of `Stack` at this point, make sure of this
6. add the `ElevatedButton` to the `children` property as well, it should be a sibling of the `Scaffold` widget
7. wrap the `ElevatedButton` you created with a `Postioned` widget.
8. set the `left` property of `Positioned` to 0, `left: 0,`
9. now rotate the button by wrapping it with a `Transform.rotate` widget.
10. set the `angle` property to `pi` from the `dart:math` build the library of dart.

Comment: what about changing the layout between signup and sign in without changing the whole screen... I want the buttons to stiĺl in the main layout

Comment: there us more solutions for this, easiest way is ti wrao that whole button with a `Hero` widget, with setting a `heroTag` then use it on both screens